# mySQL : using BETWEEN in table?

Tags: c#, mysql, between

I have a table that includes some student group name, lesson time, day names  like Schedule. I am using C# with MySql and I want to find  which lesson is when user press button from table.

I can find it by entering the exact value like in the table, e.g. 08:30 or 10:25. But I want to make that getting system time and checking that it is between 08:30 and 10:25 or 10:25 and 12:30. Then I can say that it is the first or second lesson.

I have also table includes Table_Time column has 5 record like 08:20 , 10:25 , 12:20 so on. 
Could I  use  like :

```
select Lesson_Time 
from mydb.clock 
where Lesson_Time between (current time)-30 AND (current time)+30
```

Or can I use between operator  between two columns (like creating Lesson_Time_Start and Lesson_Time_End) and comparing current time  like  `Lesson_Start_Time < current time < Lesson_End_Time`?

**EDIT:**
More precisely ,problem is how can I check current time  is  which record

I have table like

```
Time_ID  | Lesson_Time 
    1       08:30
    2       10:25
    3       12:20
    4       14:15
    5       16:10
```

And When I press some button I want to check that current time when I pressed button is it equel to which Time_ID 
Forexample I pressed button at 09:15 and it must select 1`th record , if I pressed button at 12:00 it must select 2`th record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try something like this.

```
select
    Time_ID,
    Lesson_Time
from
    mydb.clock
where
    Lesson_Time <= TIME(NOW())
order by
    Lesson_Time DESC
limit 0, 1
```

The query is limited to lesson time records prior to the current time sorted descending by time and returns only the first record, which should be the record you want. (Note, however, that midnight can complicate matters.)

Comment: But it does not work on C#. Is there another implementation for C#?

Comment: @Meko how would it not work with C#? You're issuing the query to mySQL, aren't you?

Comment: @Pekka Yes.Other queries works but this not return any value.

Comment: @Meko well, maybe there is no data to query?

Comment: )) if no data how in MySql Workbench shows it? Also I found my mistake.It was syntax of time.C# DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm") solved problem.I think MySql time syntax vas the same with my time declaration in table but C# has another )) It means that was my fault.sorry for disturbing ))

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you want to do, but I think you are looking for [DATE_ADD and DATE_SUB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add):

```
SELECT Lesson_Time from mydb.clock
 WHERE Lesson_Time between DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) AND 
                           DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE);
```

provided Lesson_Time is a proper `DATETIME` field, this should work.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply.I though like your solution before but here problem if time is 08:50 and it will -30 min 08:20 but in my table first record starts from 08:30

Comment: You can also say "NOW() + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE".

Comment: @Meko so you want to catch the next 30 minute interval? That's different. I wouldn't know an elegant solution in mySQL dor that. Can you update your question accordingly?